# How to print items from a dictionary when multiple values share the same key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary below that I'm trying to print the date for a certain day from. However, I'm getting a `KeyError`:

```
{
 'length': 601,
 'maxPageLimit': 2500,
 'totalRecords': 601,
 'data': [{'date': '2021-12-13', 'newCases': 97},
          {'date': '2021-12-12', 'newCases': 64},
          {'date': '2021-12-10', 'newCases': 108}, 
          {'date': '2021-12-09', 'newCases': 129}]

}
```

I am hoping to be able to print just 2021-12-13 and 97 for example

Comment: Hi, it is important for the community that you demonstrate that you are *also* working to solve your issue. The best way to do that is to include the **text** based version of the code you have so far, even if it is not quite right. It would probably be helpful to see what output you expect given your input as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `date` key in your top-level dictionary. You need to index into `data` and then choose one of the dictionaries from that value before getting a `date`:

```
>>> dx = {
...  'length': 601,
...  'maxPageLimit': 2500,
...  'totalRecords': 601,
...  'data': [{'date': '2021-12-13', 'newCases': 97},
...           {'date': '2021-12-12', 'newCases': 64}],
... }
>>> dx.get('data')
[{'date': '2021-12-13', 'newCases': 97}, {'date': '2021-12-12', 'newCases': 64}]
>>> dx.get('data')[0]
{'date': '2021-12-13', 'newCases': 97}
>>> dx.get('data')[0].get('date')
'2021-12-13'
```

Also, note that multiple values **do not** share the same key. You have multiple dictionaries in a list, each of which have matching keys - but they are not the same dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

dates are used as values in your program so you need to use some kind of loop to access the required date.

```
for date in d['data']:
    if date['date'] == foo:
        # do your processing
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's currently setup, you have your top-most dictionary with keys: length, maxPage, TotalyRecords and data. And then inside of data, you have a list with 2 indexes, each index being it's own dictionary.

If you wanted to get the dictionary for dec 13th, it'd be:

```
dict['data'][0] # First we go to the "data" key and get that. Then inside of the 
                data key we get index 0, which is {'date': '2021-12-13', 'newCases': 97}
```

If you wanted specifically the number of newcases, for example, it'd be:

```
dict['data'][0]['newCases'])
```

It's just about working your way down the chain of nested dictionaries and lists you have. Though there's probably a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do tbh